# suPHP / PHP script timeout

Tags: php, mysql, timeout, suphp

After my host enabled suPHP, a previously working script has been timing out after ~3min *(it varies, but the script has not run for more then 3, AFAIK)*.
The odd part is, the script is not throwing any errors that I can see *(and yes, full PHP error reporting/logging is enabled and all MYSQL queries have been checked for errors, also)* it simply stops.
Refreshing the page will load more of the data the script is supposed to process *(probably because the MYSQL queries have been cached...)*, but if there is a lot of data to process it never fully executes.
The other oddity is that I can run test scripts for over 10 minutes on the same host w/ `set_time_limit(0);` / etc.

Anyone else had to deal with this, or know what is causing the timeout and how to fix it *(assuming that dropping suPHP is not an option)*.  There was also a simultaneous update from PHP 5.2.x to 5.3.x, but I doubt that is causing the issue. :/

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when memory runs out - the script just ends without error. If you have a loop, try using the memory functions to dump the memory status. Also, use phpinfo() to see what your maximum memory allowance is - the switch to suPHP may have changed that to your detriment.

Comment: Nice idea, but the script it written pretty well so it uses memory pretty consistently.  The usage never went above 6.7MB which is about 1/10 the limit, and it was using less memory then the peak usage when it crashed. :(

Comment: Interesting thought, never found any of those in the error logs I can access though.  Fortunately suPHP is gone now, so this is no longer an issue.
I was able to narrow it down to suPHP timing out based on MYSQL activity, though I'm not sure exactly what (e.g. query limit, overall MYSQL time per-script, or a per-query time limit etc.). :/